# How to add dynamic open routes in Angular?

Tags: angularjs

In my [Angular](https://angularjs.org/) app I a restricting redirects with the following code within `run()` in my `app.js`

```
 var restrictedPage = $.inArray($location.path(), ['/login', '/register']) === -1;
 var loggedIn = $rootScope.globals.currentUser;
 if (restrictedPage && !loggedIn) {
     $location.path('/login');
 }
```

I would want to add `/route/action/:myParameter` also to be added as a part of `login` and `register`, where `myParameter` is a variable.

Is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do this manually, you can run the following against the $location.path() variable.

```
var toFind = '/route/action/'
var path   = $location.path()
if (path.substring(0, toFind.length) === toFind) {
  var myParameter = path.substring(toFind.length)
  ...
}
```

If you have more than one route like this however, consider using `angular-route`, which allows nicer syntax, eg:

```
routeProvider.when('/route/action/:myParameter', ...)
```